# How do I reduce the border spacing in table?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two rows, where there is one h1 heading in the left column. The two other columns is normal paragraphs with strong text.

The two right columns in first row goes alright, but on the second row there is too much vertical space between them. It is pretty obvious that it is the h1 which increases the vertical space between them. But how can I fix that, if possible at all? Do I really need to leave the h1 out of the table?

[image]

```css
table {
   width: 80%; 
   margin-left: 2%; 
   border-collapse: separate; 
   border-spacing: 0 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h1>Some big text</h1></td>
    <td><p><strong>Some</strong></p>
    <td><p><strong>smaller text</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><p><strong>Here come</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>Second row</strong></p></td>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That spacing is most likely from the default margin on the `h1` and `p` tags, reset them and see.

```css
table {
  width: 80%; 
  margin-left: 2%; 
  border-collapse: separate; 
  border-spacing: 0 1px;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid aqua; /*for demo purpose*/
}
table h1, table p {
  margin: 0; /*reset the margin*/
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><h1>Some big text</h1></td>
    <td><p><strong>Some</strong></p>
    <td><p><strong>smaller text</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><p><strong>Here come</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>Second row</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Edit:** I figured out (see comments below) what OP refers about the *border spacing*. It's both the empty `<td>`, and the `border-collapse` style. To combine those two `<td>`s, you can use `rowspan`. To get rid of the small space amount the lines, use `border-collapse:collapse`.

```css
table {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  border-collapse: collapse; /*set it to collapse*/
}
td {
  border: 1px solid aqua; /*for demo purpose*/
}
table h1, table p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><h1>Some big text</h1></td>
    <td><p><strong>Some</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>smaller text</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><p><strong>Here come</strong></p></td>
    <td><p><strong>Second row</strong></p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Boya! There is just a little space between row one and row two now (but not significant, I can live with that). The rest is fabolous, thanks!

Comment: It's from the `border-spacing: 0 1px;` if you make it all `0` that should be fixed. You can also use `border-collapse: collapse;` there will be no spacing.

Comment: Added `<td rowspan="*number of rows*"><h1>Some big text</h1></td>`.

Comment: That got rid of it. Changing the border-spacing from 1px to 0 didn't change anything, probably because of the empty <td>'s (which rowspan got rid of).

Comment: I made some edits above, and I think all your concerns should be answered. There is one more thing, it's missing a `</tr>` in your original table.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the margin from the h1 like so.

```
h1 {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up that 0 units should not include px in CSS. It should just be: h1{margin:0;}

While it will render properly, this is not proper syntax and won't clear validation.

Comment: Thanks @Korgue I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you can do. First, is making the `h1` smaller in height, by reducing its `margin` and its parent `padding`.

Also, you can use the `rowspan` attribute in the `td` which contains your `h1` instead of having a empty `td` on the second row.

The HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"><h1>Some big text</h1></td>
        <td><p><strong>Some</strong></p>
        <td><p><strong>smaller text</strong></p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><p><strong>Here come</strong></p></td>
        <td><p><strong>Second row</strong></p></td>
</table>
```

And the CSS:

```
table {
    width: 80%; 
    margin-left: 2%; 
    border-collapse: separate; 
    border-spacing: 0 1px;
}

table tr td {
    padding: 0;
}

table tr td h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

table tr td p {
    margin: 0;
}
```